# Two-way git mirror

Tags: git

I'm interested in setting up a local git repo to be a mirror of a remote repo. I've read a few potentially related posts, however the key difference is that I need read-write access on both repos.

Most of the time, users will work against Repo A, however there will be times when they're working against Repo B, and these need to stay in sync via server-to-server traffic.

What's the best approach here?

As it may complicate the situation, I'll add a note. The ideal way in this environment for devs to switch between master repos is to change the IP address of the repo via `/etc/hosts` - e.g. Repo A is called "gitserver" when in the office and Repo B is called "gitserver" when remote.

Comment: This seems remarkably complex, and fragile, since it will be impossible to guarantee atomic updates against both repos.  Why do you require write access to both?

Comment: @EdwardThomson The short answer is that bandwidth between Repo A and Repo B is relatively limited.

Comment: Making this work *is* going to be fragile: you'll need updates to A to lock out updates to B, and vice versa, using a distributed lock (and probably a timeout mechanism etc) and using that from pre-receive and/or update hooks.  Devs who get an error ("locked, retry") will have to retry the push (and if the lock was sensible and the sync succeeded, merge-or-rebase first as it will no longer be fast-forward).  You could build this with one of the *MQ's, probably.

Comment: Phil, what is the purpose of this mirror setup? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? I'm asking because, if you explain the reason for this setup, then maybe someone can give advice on an alternative solutions to the same problem.

Comment: I've changed jobs since, but the use case here was basically to allow two physical locations with poor inter-office bandwidth each have a 'master', so that when devs travel between offices with laptops they don't suffer from horrible push/pull times (a lot of binary assets were stored).

Comment: i'm facing the exact same problem myself.