# Automatically sync 2 writable git repositories

Tags: git, synchronization

I am working in a small office, where we are using **git** with a **central repository at a windows share**, where we can PUSH to and PULL from.
To be able to work from home, travel etc, we want to have a possibility to reach a central repo from "the outside world". Our internet connection is very, very slow, so it is no possibility to have just one central repository "inside" or "outside".

My simple attempt was the following:

- Make a central repository at the internal WIN network share: `git init --bare`
- Make one "outside" (e.g. github or an external WIN share or anything else)
- At the internal repo call `git remote add EXTERNALREPO <pathToIt>`
- and make a batch running every x minutes/hours, saying `git fetch --tags EXTERNALREPO`, `git push --tags EXTERNALREPO`

When working "inside", clone/push/pull the internal repo, when on the road, use the external repo for that.

Question: **Is this the way to go, is there a better way, or am I completely wrong?**

Related:

1. [Two-way git mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780746/two-way-git-mirror) – 
   I do not think that wee need locking as we are not so many people.
2. [Safe master-master setup with git? (writable git mirror)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588296/safe-master-master-setup-with-git-writable-git-mirror)
3. [How to keep 2 git repositories in sync automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596503/how-to-keep-2-git-repositories-in-sync-automatically) – As far as I know, a push lasts as long as it take to run all the hooks, AND since using a windows share, the CLIENT has to run it, so it wouldn't be a solution.

**Update 1**: I now came up with a slightly adjusted configuration.

- INTERNAL repo on an internal Windows Share: `git init --bare`
- EXTERNAL repo on an external Windows Share: `git init --bare`
- Both repos:

  ```
  git config receive.denyNonFastForwards 1
  git config receive.denyDeletes 1
  git remote add {INTERNAL|EXTERNAL} file:///...
  ```
- Every x seconds/minutes/hours, call `git push --all {INTERNAL|EXTERNAL}` and `git push --tags {INTERNAL|EXTERNAL}`, **at first at the internal, then at the external repository**.

Answer (score 0):

1. "repository at a windows share" is **The Bad&Ugly Idea (tm)**
2. Use post-* hook in INTERNAL for pushing to EXTERNAL as it happens
3. Pseudo-CVCS in DVCS is ugly (everybody can bring local travel-repo to workplace and sync from it)

Comment: 1. Why? I thought, git could easily cope with that.

2. Isn't it correct that a PUSH lasts as long as all hooks need to complete? In that case, the gain from using the INTERNAL from inside would disappear. And, how could we get the changes from the EXTERNAL repo to the inside one?

3. What do you mean with that statement and the paren sentence?